# SOQL Performance Impact

Tags: soql

Does a Nested soql query has more impact on the overall performance or does it have the same performance impact as writing a normal soql(without nested query) since there is only a single server trip involved in both the cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on context and data skew. For the API, you may end up burning more API calls than two separate queries, as the children can result in their own cursors; a single API call might bloom into 50+ to get all the children. However, if the data skew is nominal, this isn't an issue. Also, you have to take care to access the cursors in order, or they'll be lost. This means you can't process parents then children, but instead must process parents and children together.

For Batch Apex, using them results in a significant startup penalty; you should only use nested queries in the execute method. There is never an appropriate time to use a subquery in the start method's query locator. It will at best have no improvement on performance, and in most cases, offer worse performance.

For most other cases, it doesn't matter which you use, though, assuming you have normal levels of data volume and skew. Use whichever you find easiest to use in your application.